# css - container div shrink-to-fit contents

Tags: css

I'm hitting a wall here, hope someone can help.

I've got a container div with a black background that I need to dynamically "shrink-to-fit" the contents within it.  I've tried display: inline-block and several other usual fixes for this, but to no avail.

The content inside is a large number of div boxes that are flush:left.  This number of boxes can change dynamically each time the page is loaded.

Here's my css:

```
#blackboard {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2px;
    max-width: 580px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box {
    height: 40px;
    width: 34px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1px;
    float: left;
    background-color: White;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="blackboard">

<div class="box" id="topbox1"></div><div class="box" id="topbox2"></div><div class="box" id="topbox3"></div><div class="box" id="topbox4"></div><div class="box" id="topbox5"></div><div class="box" id="topbox6"></div><div class="box" id="topbox7"></div><div class="box" id="topbox8"></div><div class="box" id="topbox9"></div><div class="box" id="topbox10"></div><div class="box" id="topbox11"></div><div class="box" id="topbox12"></div><div class="box" id="topbox13"></div><div class="box" id="topbox14"></div><div class="box" id="topbox15"></div><div class="box" id="topbox16"></div><div class="box" id="topbox17"></div><div class="box" id="topbox18"></div><div class="box" id="topbox19"></div><div class="box" id="topbox20"></div><div class="box" id="topbox21"></div><div class="box" id="topbox22"></div><div class="box" id="topbox23"></div><div class="box" id="topbox24"></div><div class="box" id="topbox25"></div><div class="box" id="topbox26"></div><div class="box" id="topbox27"></div><div class="box" id="topbox28"></div><div class="box" id="topbox29"></div><div class="box" id="topbox30"></div><div class="box" id="topbox31"></div><div class="box" id="topbox32"></div><div class="box" id="topbox33"></div><div class="box" id="topbox34"></div><div class="box" id="topbox35"></div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

Easier to see it here though:

http://jsfiddle.net/pbspry/L8e34tvx/

Basically just need the container div (black) to wrap so that there is equal blackspace (just a few pixels) around the entire grid, even if the window is resized or the browser's zoom settings are increased/decreased.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

Looks like this can't really be done without javascript, which I don't want to use for a number of reasons.

The easiest fix seems to be to select a certain number of boxes per row, and then put a "clear:both" after that number.  This forces a line break and then the outside div properly shrinks to fit (even at different browser zoom levels).

Comment: Good question. Not relevant but something worth doing would be do change the `#blackboard` div from `display:inline-block;` to `display:table;`.

Answer (score 14):

Your container already has a shrink-to-fit width, because of `display: inline-block`.

The algorithm is defined in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) as

> 1. Calculate the **preferred width** by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur
> 2. Also calculate the **preferred minimum width**, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm.
> 3. Find the **available width**: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of `margin-left`,
>      `border-left-width`, `padding-left`, `padding-right`,
>      `border-right-width`, `margin-right`, and the widths of any relevant
>      scroll bars.
>
> Then the **shrink-to-fit width** is:
>
> ```
> min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)
> ```

In your case,

- The preferred width is 100 * 38px = 3800px
- The preferred minimum width is 38px
- The available width is much probably something between 38 and 3800px.

Then the shrink-to-fit width would be the available width. And that would be clamped with `max-width: 580px`.

AFAIK there is no way to achieve your desired behavior without JS. And probably the reason is that a small change could push some elements to other lines and produce a big change in the container's width.